# Meteor.call() on server side got Error: Method not found [404]

Tags: amazon-s3, meteor

I am new to meteor. I'm getting an error trying to call a server method on the server side in the folder server/. I can't figure what I'm missing. If someone can help that would be great. Thanks

Error :

```
lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: Method not found [404]
    at _.extend.apply (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:1251)
    at _.extend.call (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:1221)
    at app/server/config.js:2:9
    at app/server/config.js:4:3
```

Method:

```
var s3_options = {
    key: "***",
    secret: "***",
    bucket: "**",
    directory: "/"
}   
Meteor.call("S3_config", s3_options);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to this :

```
 Meteor.call('Methodname'); //here 'Methodname' is your method name
```

and also provide method body like to shown below where you need:

```
 Meteor.methods
  ({
    Methodname: function () 
    {
    //here write your Body
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me to better understand what's going on. In fact, the package Meteor-S3-Progress has been updated one week ago and they removed the method "S3_config".
For curious people: https://github.com/digilord/Meteor-S3-Progress

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the name of the method you'd like to call, i.e. `Meteor.call("myMethod")`.